# Twelfth man in cricket

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology

I heard a term called [twelfth man](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/239756.html) in cricket.

W.K.T, there are 4 players apart from the playing 11.

- Is it necessary to fix a particular player as 12th man before
  starting the match?
- What is the difference between the twelfth man and the other substitutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms#Twelfth_man):

> #### Twelfth man
>
> Traditionally, **the first [substitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_%28cricket%29) player** who fields when a member of the fielding side is injured.

So the twelfth man is one of those substitutes. The only difference is that he has priority to field than other substitutes.

> Is it necessary to fix a particular player as 12th man before starting the match?

There it no laws for the twelfth player in [laws of cricket](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-1-the-players/) regarding nomination of the 12th or substitute player. But in [ICC's match playing conditions <sup>*PDF*</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4ae08b48-04%20Standard%20ODI_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf), a captain shall nominate 4 substitutes along with playing XI. There is no specification of 12th man.

Comment: Actually, none of the four selected players has priority over the others. Any of them can be selected to field for any player and that selected substitute is then termed the twelfth man.